# Data source rejected establishment of connection, message from server: "Too many connections"

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am using hibenate and spring and getting below exception ween we hit from jmeter with 250 users

> "Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"

hibernate_cfg.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">500</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>`
```

Spring

```
<bean id="dataSource" scope="prototype" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"> 
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>${dbDriver}</value>
    </property>  
    <property name="url">
        <value>${dbURL}</value> 
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>${dbUsername}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>${dbPassword}</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a message from the server, so, I'd check what's the number of connected clients that the server is reporting. If this is an expected number, like 500 or so, then I'd increase this limit on the server, if you really expect that level of concurrency for your application. Otherwise, reduce the number of clients.

A bit of background on how it works: each client is a thread on the server, and each thread will consume at least one connection. If you are doing it right, the connection will return to the pool once the thread finishes (ie: once the response is sent to the client). So, in the best case, you'd have 500 connections if you have around 500 users connected. If are seeing a number close to a multiple of the number of concurrent users (ie: 2 users, 4 connections), then you might be consuming more than one connection per thread (that's the price you pay for not using the data source provided by your application server, if you are using one). If you are seeing a really high number (like, 10 times the number of users), then you might have a connection leak somewhere. This might happen if you forget to close the connection.

I'd really suggest to use an EntityManager managed by your application server, and using a DataSource also provided by it. Then, you'd not have to worry about managing the connection pooling.

Comment: I could, but it's better if you take a look at the documentation. There's a good Java EE tutorial at Oracle's website and there's also a good Hibernate documentation on its website.

Comment: I am using `session = Hy5HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();` and closing finally block

Comment: what is the diff between openSession() and getCurrentSession(), which one is the best one

Comment: I have added connection pool in spring data source now, It s working fine

Comment: `<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close" >
        <property name="driverClass" value="${dbDriver}"></property>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${dbURL}"></property>
        <property name="user" value="${dbUsername}"></property>
        <property name="password" value="${dbPassword}"></property>
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="5"></property>
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="50"/>
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5"/>
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="3000"/>`

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem is that your datasource doesn't have a connections pool.
from org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource javadocs:

> **NOTE: This class is not an actual connection pool; it does not actually
>    * pool Connections.**

It is also say in the javadocs of that class to use Apache's Jakarta Commons DBCP in case u do need connection pool.

> If you need a "real" connection pool outside of a J2EE container,
>   consider  [Apache's
>   Jakarta Commons DBCP](http://jakarta.apache.org/commons/dbcp)  or C3P0.  Commons DBCP's
>   BasicDataSource and C3P0's ComboPooledDataSource are full  connection
>   pool beans, supporting the same basic properties as this class  plus
>   specific settings (such as minimal/maximal pool size etc).

I used it and it worked like a charm :)

Hoped I helped.

Answer (score 1):

if connection created every time it may caused this problem. Solution is simple. Single on. connection for each sessin. So that  I am publishing some code on bottom of my post.  Check incorrect and correct coding. 1-incorrect,2-correct

```
private  EntityManagerFactory emf = null;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public BaseDAO() {


        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("aaHIBERNATE");
        persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass()
                .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];


}

private static EntityManagerFactory emf = null;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public BaseDAO() {

    if (emf == null) {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("aaHIBERNATE");}
        persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass()
                .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to trace it in application and database server both.

1. Check the database configuration for possible maximum open connections.
2. If you are using the database connections from another clients, Check for the current opened connections in database server.
3. Check your application if you are opening too many connections and not closing them.

You need to increase the value of max open connections in database server settings.

To change max open connections you need to edit `max_connections` and `max_user_connections` in my.cnf file under database server.

You can also grant/edit max number of connections with per user. [more info available here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-resources.html)

Comment: I have given unlimited connection in mysql wamp server

Comment: mysql defalt max_connections = 151, How many number of connection should I use for 1000 users per application

Comment: max_connections should be, what you expect to be using your application simultaneously. In case if there are multiple applications accessing the database, you need to include those connections also.